# Does a "clamp" number function exist in PHP?

Tags: php, clamp

I wrote a function to "clamp" numbers in PHP, but I wonder if this function exists natively in the language.

I read PHP.net documentation in the math section, but I couldn't find it.

Basically what my function does is that it accepts a variable, an array of possible values, and a default value, this is my function's signature:

```php
function clamp_number($value, $possible_values, $default_value)
```

If `$value` does not match any of the `$possible_values` then it defaults to `$default_value`

I think my function would be way faster if PHP already provides it natively because I'm using quite often in my program.

Comment: Unless it's a defined integer range (in which case you could use `filter_var`), nope, no built in. To determine wether we can speed up your custom function we'd need to see it.

Comment: To "clamp" a number means to restrict it to a maximum (or minimum) value.  That is not what you are asking for here.

Comment: That's why I quoted clamp, for lack of a better word.

Comment: It's a sanitizer. It restricts a value to any of the predefined values, and replaces any violations with the default value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$value = in_array($value, $possible_values, true) ? $value : $default_value;
```

Ref: https://php.net/in_array

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing to see if the value falls within the possible options, I just thought that PHP could already have it as part of the language, probably like an alias... similar to put_file_contents

Comment: I just rollbacked because the second returned `true` or `$default_value`. Leave your post correct when it's correct ;-)

Comment: @AlanChavez: No such built-in function exists.

Comment: I'm marking this question as correct, even though I wasn't asking for the code :)

Answer (score 67):

It seems as though you are just trying to find a number within a set.  An actual clamp function will make sure a number is within 2 numbers (a lower bounds and upper bounds).  So psudo code would be `clamp(55, 1, 10)` would produce `10` and `clamp(-15, 1, 10)` would produce `1` where `clamp(7, 1, 10)` would produce `7`.  I know you are looking for more of an `in_array` method but for those who get here from Google, here is how you can clamp in PHP without making a function (or by making this into a function).

```
max($min, min($max, $current))
```

For example:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 10;
$current = 55;
$clamped = max($min, min($max, $current));
// $clamped is now == 10
```

A simple clamp method would be:

```
function clamp($current, $min, $max) {
    return max($min, min($max, $current));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think is worth to know that a PHP *clamp()* function was proposed for version PHP 8.2:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/clamp

If it would have been approved, it would exist in the core.

(The *clamp()* request for comments (RFC) has been withdrawn.)

> I have made the difficult decision to withdraw the RFC, I currently don't have the resources or bandwidth for it. If anyone would like to take it over they are more than welcome to, I apologize to anyone who was looking forward to this.  *(Kim Hallberg
> "thinkverse"; Jun 2023; [ref](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/7191#issuecomment-1587410340))*

Answer (score 0):

[$min,$max],
$value:

```
$result = ($value >= $min && $value <= $max) ? $value: ($value < $min ? $min : $max)
```